# How does this method add the size of all BST nodes?

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I do not understand how sum is being incremented since it is reset to 1 each time that the method is called. I do know that the memory is being stored in a stack, but I don't see where the actual summation happens. Also how much more memory is saved when the Variable sum is declared inside of the method rather then outside of the method.

```
private int size(BSTNode current) {
        if (current == null) {
            return 0;
        }
    int sum = 1;
    sum += size(current.getLeft());
    sum += size(current.getRight());
    return sum;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, you joined as the head of a division of a company and want to know the total number of people who are working in that division. Also, there are 2 head officers , one for engineering and one for business. Now, to count the number of people, you can go around the office and count. ( But that's tedious and besides, what's the point of being the head of the division.)

Or, what you can do is ask your engineering head to find out the people working under him , say `x` and ask business head to find out the people working under him, say `y`. So, the total number of people working in the division is `x+y+1` ( 1 is for you ).

Now, you can assume that the engineering head will have 2 supervisors under him and he asks them to find out the number of people each supervisor is supervising. So, the total number of people in engineering team is `people_under_supervisor_1 + people_under_supervisor_2 + 1` (1 for the engineering head) . And so, on.

Similarly, you can assume a similar process involved in finding the number of people in business department by the business head.

That code is doing the same thing, find the size of **left subtree** , find the size of **right subtree** and adding 1 for the **current node**.
This is how the algorithm is working. I hope this analogy helps.

Now, regarding "**how much more memory is saved when the Variable sum is declared inside of the method rather then outside of the method.**" 
Actually ***more memory is used when you declare a local variable in a recursive function***. When you declare any local variable a memory location is allocated in the stack and that memory location can't be used for some other purpose until the scope of that local variable completes. So, when the next function is called `size(current.getLeft())` , all the variables stay in the stack and the a new memory location for the local variable `size` gets created by calling `size(current.getLeft())`. The instance of `size` stays in memory as long as the function is still not returned the result.

Look at this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_8-ht2AKyH4 to get a clearer idea of stack.

Answer (score 0):

What your code does:

```
int sum = 1;                      // +1 for current node
sum += size(current.getLeft());   // +size of leftSubtree of current node
sum += size(current.getRight());  // +size of rightSubtree of current node
```

You are starting from root, going down to each node till leaf nodes, and then returning back from bottom, as it goes up, +1 is done for each of the node.

Use of variable name `sum` is misleading when actually you are trying count the number of nodes. Use names like `count` or `node_count`